# How to use azure Storage Sync group to sync on-premises File Server Disks to azure IaaS VM folders

Tags: azure, azure-devops, synchronization, azure-storage

I am finding a solution of how to sync an on-premises server with two disks (Disk:C,Disk:D) to an Azure IaaS Server folder, if you know something about it, please let me know.

For ex: On-premises Server A with Disk D and E.  Azure Storage Sync, Azure IaaS VM (Server B) Disk D have two Folders.

Server A  Disk D's "share folder d" ⇔ Azure Files ⇔　Azure IaaS VM D folder→Directory "shareD";

Server A Disk E's "share folder e" ⇔Azure files　⇔　Azure IaaS VM D folder →Directory "shareE".

Is it possible to achieve the goal with one Storage Sync Group.

I except the output of an on-premises server's two disks can sync to one Azure AaaS VM's folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a PM in Azure Storage team. Assuming that you are running Windows on these IaaS servers, You can consider leveraging Azure File Sync to sync the drives. See additional details on AFS deployment here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-sync-files-deployment-guide?tabs=azure-portal. You will need to use separate sync groups. Azure File Sync doesn't support server endpoints from the same server in the same sync group. The recommendation is to create two sync groups (two Azure file shares). One sync group for the D: volume. Another sync group for the E: volume.

I will be happy to get on the call with you to better understand your scenario and provide recommendations.

Aung Oo

Microsoft Azure Storage Team

Comment: Thanks for your kind explain. I have another question about Azure File Sync cloud tiering, and I had created a new post, can you check it? Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi Arthur, can you please send an email with your question to AzureFilesPM@microsoft.com so that we can reply. Thanks!